# Tensorflow-js: what is the equivalent of `tf.placeholder`?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am new to tensorflow-js but have used tensorflow python quite a bit in the past. I am trying to do some modelling inside a web app at the moment.

I need a tensorflow to be built at runtime (because of depending on user interactions). The problem is mathematically basic, it is a 1d to 1d curve fitting (`y` is a function of `x` with some free parameters to be fitted).

My code looks like:

```
let x_train = tf.tensor1d( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], "float32");
let y_train = tf.tensor1d( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], "float32");
let slope = tf.variable( tf.scalar(0), true, 'slope');
let intercept = tf.variable( tf.scalar(0), true, 'intercept');
let x = tf.variable( tf.scalar(0), false, 'input');
let y = tf.add(tf.mul(slope, x), intercept);
const optimizer = tf.train.adam();


let model = tf.model( {inputs: x, outputs: y});
let lossAndOptimizer = {
  loss: 'meanSquaredError',
  optimizer: 'adam',
};
```

But I get the error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Variable<Rank.R0>' is not assignable to type 'SymbolicTensor | SymbolicTensor[]'.
```

telling me that a `tf.variable` cannot be used as a model input. I looked into the documentation for the tfjs equivalent of `tf.placeholder` but could not find it. What can I use here?

ps: I need to use `tf.model` because of cases I want to generalise this modelling later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tf.placeholder is using when constructing a graph. There is no equivalent of tf.placeholder in tfjs because it currently supports only the eager execution. As a matter of fact, starting from tensorflow 2.0, there is no longer tf.placeholder.

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/models_and_layers) is a tutorial on how to use tf.model to create non acyclic graph. It is unclear what you want to do with x and y. If your goal is to set the weight of your layer, you can use the method `setWeights`. On the other hand if x and y are the input and output layer, they have to be constructed using tf.input instead of tf.variable

If the goal is  rather to use x and y respectively as features and label, it can be done using the predict function during training

Comment: Thanks for the input, indeed I had to find a ugly but functional way of doing my thing. No placeholder, noted. I feel like changing my mind to eager execution for tf2.0 is gonna be a challenge!